# Why does this generic method call not match?

Tags: c#, generics

I have an `Address` class:

```
public class Address
{
    //Some stuff
}
```

and there's a corresponding `*Wrapper` class to enforce certain rules on how to
use the `Address` class:

```
public class AddressWrapper : IWrapped<Address>
{
    private Address _wrapped;

    public Address GetWrapped()
    {
        return _wrapped;
    }

    //And some more
}
```

where `IWrapped` is defined as:

```
public interface IWrapped<T>
{
    T GetWrapped();
}
```

I have the following generic class for saving these entities (there are other
entities that follow this pattern of `Entity` and `EntityWrapper`):

```
public class GenericRepository
{
    private GenericRepository() { }

    public static void Add<T>(IWrapped<T> entity)
    {
        //Do something
    }

    public static void AddList<T>(IList<IWrapped<T>> entities)
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

and I have this test code:

```
[Test]
public void UseGenericRepository()
{
    AddressWrapper addrW = new AddressWrapper();
    addrW.AddrLine1 = "x";
    addrW.AddrLine2 = "y";
    addrW.AddrLine3 = "z";
    addrW.City = "Starling City";
    //This works as expected
    GenericRepository.Add<Address>(addrW);

    IList<AddressWrapper> addrList = new List<AddressWrapper>();
    //Fill up the addrList

    //This gives error: best overloaded method match has some invalid
    //arguments
    GenericRepository.AddList<Address>(addrList);
}
```

`AddressWrapped` is of type `IWrapped<Address>` (i.e., it implements it) and
`Address` is the type parameter being given to the `AddList` method, so the
types should line up.  I know that this is due to my limited knowledge of C#
generics (familiar with Java generics), but can't figure out what's wrong here
--- it **should** work.

This probably doesn't make any difference, but here's my config:

- NHibernate 4.x
- .NET Framework (4.5)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the edit and the link.

Comment: [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/farucU) showing the problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NB:** Please see the answer by @StefanSteinegger, it is especially enlightening.

What worked for me was changing the way I was defining `addrList`, from:

```
IList<AddressWrapper> addrList = new List<AddressWrapper>();
```

to:

```
IList<IWrapped<Address>> addrList = new List<IWrapped<Address>>();
```

However, I am also changing the signature of the `GenericRepository.AddList<T>(..)` method to take an `IEnumerable` as that also helps indicate that the input is read-only. So:

```
public static void AddList<T>(IEnumerable<IWrapped<T>> entities)
{
    //Do some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the missing type variance of `IList<T>`. (`IList<int>` is not an `IList<object>`).

Use `IEnumerable<T>`, because it is covariant:

```
public static void AddList<T>(IEnumerable<IWrapped<T>> entities)
{
    //Do something
}
```

Reason: If you get an instance of `List<AddressWrapper>`, the compiler doesn't know if it is compatible with **any** possible implementation of `IList<IWrapped<T>>`. Assume another class that implements `IWrapped<T>`. It wouldn't be compatible when writing to the List. Even though you don't write to the list in `AddList`, the compiler only accepts compatible types. `IEnumerable<T>` cannot be written, so it can be variant.

Not related to the question I suggest to use covariance for your own interface as well:

```
public interface IWrapped<out T>
```

to make `IWrapped<Thing>` compatible with `IWrapped<SpecificThing>`.

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx

Comment: Thanks for this answer: it helped me understand more than just my specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

To make this clear by an example. Would would you expect happen if we had two types implement `IWrapped<T>`?

```
public class AddressWrapper : IWrapped<Address>
{
    private Address _wrapped;

    public Address GetWrapped()
    {
        return _wrapped;
    }

    //And some more
}

public class OtherWrapper : IWrapped<MailBox>
{
    public MailBox GetWrapped()
    {
        throw new MailBox();
    }
}
```

And we tried to add them to a third list inside `AddList<T>`:

```
public static void AddList<T>(IList<IWrapped<T>> entities)
{
   internalList = new List<IWrapped<T>>(); 
   list.AddRange(entities); // BOOM.
}
```

The type system is keeping you from making a mistake. `List<T>` isn't covariant exactly for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

At the point at which you're trying to *call* `AddList()`, for all the compiler knows, that method may add objects of *any* type that implements `IWrapper<Address>` (i.e. types that aren't `AddressWrapper`) to the passed in list.

That would be bad because the list you're trying to pass to the method doesn't want to contain anything other than `AddressWrapper`s.